# sum elements in an array that correspond to identical values in another array

Tags: sum, conditional-statements

Imagine I have an array of times of trades, and there are lots of trades occuring within a particular second. In my time array they correspond to identical values of time (no millisecond there).

I have another matrix of trade volumes.

Is there a quick way to sum those volumes that correspond to a trade within each second?
I mean is there an easier way than writing a loop?

Appreciate your help.

Conceptually:

A=[(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4)]; B=[(12 13, 14, 15, 14, 13, 11)]

How can I sum up elements of B corresponding to the identical values of A. I mean I want to get

C=[(12, 13+14+15, 14, 13+11)]

Comment: Use a database for this purpose

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by trade volumes. Give some sample data to better understand your problem.

Comment: www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShjrtAQmIVg‎

Comment: Thanks.
Trade volumes array contains the volumes of stocks traded at the particular transaction.